# Have any of the Pink Floyd's instrumental pieces been vocalized?

Tags: instrumental, pink-floyd

I wonder if there exist any vocal versions of Pink Floyd's greatest instrumentals? Especially the Endless River music and Marooned or Cluster One?

Answer (score -1):

One of the instrumental songs, *Things left unsaid* from *The Endless River* has some vocal in it.

> We certainly are underspoken and understanding
>
> But there's a lot of
> things unsaid as well
>
> We shout and argue and fight, and work it on out

Comment: Yes, I know but it's not what I meant. Talkin' Hawking also has vocals but it's not a song. Remembering Great Gig in the Sky it's not a song either.

Comment: @SovereignSun okay, running over the same old ground, what have you found?